# How to calculate Eigenvalue without using eign() function with R?

Tags: r, determinant

I understand how to calculate EIGN by hand but when I try to write code without function EIGN(), I did not have a clue.

To calculate Eigenvalue is to count all the possible c in `det(A-c*I)=0`. A is the matrix, and c is a number.

Comment: your question has a answer here on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132007/a-function-for-calculating-the-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-in-r

Comment: @Alex thanks for your link. Is it possible to do even without another library?

Comment: I think the problem then would be to write your own function to find the roots of the characteristic polynomial, maybe implementing one of the methods from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to do something in specific software. Please see advice in the Help Center about software-specific questions. Nor would it be a good fit for SO because requests for code or recommendations of code are off-topic there. How to calculate eigenvalues is surely one of the best documented problems in numerical analysis.

Answer (score 2):

There a various algos to do this. Specialists in this field can be found on https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Some good algos are: The QR algo and the Jacobi-Davidson Algo.

Some famous books are:
1. "Numerical Recipes"
2. The one Golub and Van Load
3. "Numerical Linear Algebra"
4. The book by Wilkinson, 1964

Some of the hardest cases are when the A != A'